# How to disable lock pattern/pin on lock screen with new Android 4.3 update?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, lock-screens, 4.3-jelly-bean, encryption

I just did an update on my Galaxy S3 and now it is required that I have a lock on my lock screen. Before the update, I had the simple "Swipe to Unlock."

Now, when I go into
Settings>Lock screen>screen lock, I am unable to select the swipe option. It says "turned off by administrator, encryption policy or credential storage."

Does any one know how to disable any of those so that I can go back to my swipe lock screen? It is really annoying having to type a dumb password in every time i want to get into my phone.

Comment: If you've enabled filesystem encryption or have installed a certificate, then the policy is to require a secure screen unlock method. Could you perhaps [edit] your question and add more details about the specifics of your update?

Comment: This could also be due to an email account (Exchange accounts can sometimes require device administrators).

Answer (score 1):

Just select the last option in the Security settings, "Clear Credentials".

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by decryption of memory card.

Samsung Galaxy Phone:

settings-->More-->security-->Encrypt External SD card-->disable.

After disabling go to my device-->lock screen-->Screen lock--> all the features will be enabled.
You will be able to choose your own security now.

Regards,
Hari